# Random "Uninitialized Constant" errors in staging/production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

Like many Rails applications, we have a few classes we define in the lib/ folder. We make sure to let Rails know about them in the config/application.rb file like so

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib'), Rails.root.join('lib', '**')]
```

And that has worked perfectly up until now with no problems. However recently we have been getting random occurrences of "Uninitialied Constant" errors in staging/production. Most of the times things work fine, it's just every once in a while that things break down. Opening a Rails console and the classes are always there.

I tried to better understand how Rails does the autoloading magic, so I read this great article: http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/, but nothing in it helped me.
I also tried a few things that I thought might work, like requiring all the files individually in an initializer, but nothing worked.

I'm using Ruby 2.1.1, Rails 3.2.19, Phusion Passenger 4.x. Anything else that might help? How might Constants become undefined or inaccessible from somewhere? Maybe a gem is messing with the way Rails modifies constant lookup...

Update: I have not enabled threadsafe mode

Comment: Do you have threadsafe! enabled in staging / prod? That causes issues with autoloading in rails 3.

Comment: @hjing Nope, did not enable that. I'll update the question.

Comment: adding lib and lib** is a bit odd. it should just be lib, everything in there should adhere to rails naming conventions. never require anything that is in an autoload path. can you provide some examples of the names that can't be looked up? maybe there is a pattern that's not obvious to you.